# How to check the status of the running method

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Flask service:

```py
@app.route('/')
def long_method():
   #A long blocking thread task
```

How can I add a second method to check if `long_method` is currently executing and return the corresponding message?

Comment: How about using print()?

Comment: @gunesevitan How can I use `print()` from different method to check if `long_method` is executed?

Comment: I meant do you really need another method for this? You can just add simple `print()` calls and see the `long_method()` is running or  not.

Comment: I have such requirements. Create a second method and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

`long_method` should return to the caller ASAP. It should return a unique number that will be used by the second method (lets call it `check_status`). In the server side you need to keep a dict that map this number to a running function status

```
@app.route('/')
def long_method():
   action_id = get_action_id() 
   _long_method(action_id) # call the method that takes time on another thread
   # push the action_id to a dict: action_id --> 'running'
   # when _long_method it should update the dict to action_id --> 'done'
```

`check_status` should look at this table and return the status